How to trigger MatTooltip on hover on MatChips inside a disabled MatFormField?
I'm struggling to find a solution here. Basically I have a disabled FormField that is composed by a series of MatChips, each of them with a specific tooltip.
Most of the solutions that I find online suggest to move the tooltip in an outer div, that is impossible for me since I need to add them in an NgFor inside the disabled FormField.
In code:
<form [formGroup]="fruitsForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-chip-grid 
      #chipGrid aria-label="Enter fruits" 
      formControlName="fruits" <!-- This is the disabled formField in my scenario -->
   >
      @for (fruit of fruits(); track fruit) {
      <mat-chip-row>
        <div [matTooltip]="fruit.name">{{fruit.name}}</div>
      </mat-chip-row>
      }
      <input
        ...
      />
    </mat-chip-grid>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

How would you approach the issue? What can I do to have the tooltip triggered even on a disabled chips that are disabled by the outer formfield?
A complete working example can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/c2pken?file=src%2Fexample%2Fchips-input-example.html

The tooltip is disabled by the CSS pointer-events: none, you can just override this css with pointer-events: all !important, then it will display over the disabled chips.
  ::ng-deep .show-tool-tip-disabled .mdc-text-field--disabled {
      pointer-events: all !important;
  }
  ::ng-deep .show-tool-tip-disabled .mdc-evolution-chip--disabled, 
  ::ng-deep .show-tool-tip-disabled .mdc-evolution-chip__action:disabled {
      pointer-events: all !important;
  }

Full Code:
HTML:
<form [formGroup]="fruitsForm">
  <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
    <mat-label>Favorite Fruits</mat-label>
    <mat-chip-grid
      #chipGrid
      aria-label="Enter fruits"
      formControlName="fruits"
      class="show-tool-tip-disabled"
    >
      @for (fruit of fruits(); track fruit) {
      <mat-chip-row
        (removed)="remove(fruit)"
        [editable]="true"
        (edited)="edit(fruit, $event)"
        [aria-description]="'press enter to edit ' + fruit.name"
      >
        <div [matTooltip]="fruit.name">{{fruit.name}}</div>
        <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove ' + fruit.name">
          <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-chip-row>
      }
      <input
        placeholder="New fruit..."
        [matChipInputFor]="chipGrid"
        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
        [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
      />
    </mat-chip-grid>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

TS:
import { LiveAnnouncer } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { COMMA, ENTER } from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  inject,
  signal,
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {
  MatChipEditedEvent,
  MatChipInputEvent,
  MatChipsModule,
} from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';

export interface Fruit {
  name: string;
}

/**
 * @title Chips with input
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'chips-input-example',
  templateUrl: 'chips-input-example.html',
  styleUrl: 'chips-input-example.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  styles: [
    `::ng-deep .show-tool-tip-disabled .mdc-text-field--disabled {
      pointer-events: all !important;
  }
  ::ng-deep .show-tool-tip-disabled .mdc-evolution-chip--disabled, 
  ::ng-deep .show-tool-tip-disabled .mdc-evolution-chip__action:disabled {
      pointer-events: all !important;
  }
  `,
  ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ChipsInputExample {
  readonly addOnBlur = true;
  readonly separatorKeysCodes = [ENTER, COMMA] as const;
  readonly fruits = signal<Fruit[]>([
    { name: 'Lemon' },
    { name: 'Lime' },
    { name: 'Apple' },
  ]);
  readonly announcer = inject(LiveAnnouncer);
  public fruitsForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    fruits: new FormControl({ value: [], disabled: true }),
  });

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const value = (event.value || '').trim();

    // Add our fruit
    if (value) {
      this.fruits.update((fruits) => [...fruits, { name: value }]);
    }

    // Clear the input value
    event.chipInput!.clear();
  }

  remove(fruit: Fruit): void {
    this.fruits.update((fruits) => {
      const index = fruits.indexOf(fruit);
      if (index < 0) {
        return fruits;
      }

      fruits.splice(index, 1);
      this.announcer.announce(`Removed ${fruit.name}`);
      return [...fruits];
    });
  }

  edit(fruit: Fruit, event: MatChipEditedEvent) {
    const value = event.value.trim();

    // Remove fruit if it no longer has a name
    if (!value) {
      this.remove(fruit);
      return;
    }

    // Edit existing fruit
    this.fruits.update((fruits) => {
      const index = fruits.indexOf(fruit);
      if (index >= 0) {
        fruits[index].name = value;
        return [...fruits];
      }
      return fruits;
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Ooo, I see! Thanks a lot! It solved the issue! I was thinking it was something related to angular material instead it was a simple CSS rule! So easy! Thanks again!
